# How to split text in Ruby without creating empty strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing, split

Splitting on whitespace, period, comma or double quotes, and not on single quotes:

```
str = %Q{this is the.string    to's split,real "ok" nice-like.}
str.split(/\s|\.|,|"/)
=> ["this", "is", "the", "string", "", "", "", "to's", "split", "real", "", "ok", "", "nice-like"]
```

How to eloquently remove empty strings?

How to eloquently remove strings that are shorter than MIN_LENGTH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea of using `split` is not right in this case. You should be using `scan`.

```
str = %Q{this is the.string    to's split,real "ok" nice-like.}
str.scan(/[\w'-]+/)
# => ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "ok", "nice-like"]
```

In order to match strings that are `MIN_LENGTH` or longer, do like this:

```
MIN_LENGTH = 3
str.scan(/[\w'-]{#{MIN_LENGTH},}/)
# => ["this", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "nice-like"]
```

**When to use split, when to use scan**

- When the delimiters are messy and making a regex match them is difficult, use `scan`.
- When the substrings to extract are messy and making a regex match them is difficult, use `split`.
- When you want to impose conditions on the form of the substrings to be extracted, you `scan`.
- When you want to impose conditions on the form of the delimiters, use `split`.

Comment: This is actually much better for what I was trying to do. `split` is not good because you have to figure out all the other possible delimiters, like !, --, ?, ~, :, etc.

Comment: Tobias answered the first question best: `str.split /[\s\.,"]+/`

Answer (score 8):

I'm not entirely clear on the problem domain, but if you just want to avoid the empty strings, why not split on *one or more occurrences* of your separators?

```
str.split /[\s\.,"]+/
```

Answer (score 6):

I would think a simple way to do that is as follows:

```
str.split(/\s|\.|,|"/).select{|s| s.length >= MIN_LENGTH}
```

Comment: Works and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
str.split(/\s*[.,"\s]\s*/)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve the same in multiple ways,

```
 > str.split(/[\s\.,"]/) - [""]
=> ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "ok", "nice-like"]

 > str.split(/[\s\.,"]/).select{|sub_string| sub_string.present?}
=> ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "ok", "nice-like"]

 > str.scan /\w+'?\w+/
=> ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "ok", "nice", "like"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MIN_LENGTH = 2

new_strings = str.split(/\s|\.|,|"/).reject{ |s| s.length < MIN_LENGTH }
```